# Usb Flash protection

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am developing an application based on an external usb disk drive, and I need to allow only to my application to read and write the disk drive.

What should I do to implement this task?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. You talk about drivers, for which you usually use an unmanaged language like C or C++, but yet you tag the question with *both* the C# and the VB.Net tag. Also, why would reading from a USB drive be any different from reading from any other drive?

Comment: @lesderid - I believe the OP means disk drive not driver. He wants to prevent any application (other that this own) from reading and writing to a USB flash drive

Comment: The question is still very vague. Does he want to prevent applications from accessing the whole disk, a certain partition or maybe even only one file? How does he want to do it? From his application, from a separate application? Does he want to use encryption or kernel drivers? etc.

Comment: first I mean by driver - drive second I need to allow only my application to read and write to the whole disk drive. thanks for interest

Answer (score 2):

Disk I/O is handled directly by the Windows Kernel. There is nothing you can do from .net to prevent I/O operations on the drive. You can possibly encrypt everything you write to the drive to prevent others from reading it, but that is about it.

Comment: i do it already but the problem is that this files may be deleted so i need to lock the whole disk drive or work with other file system not supported by operating system. but how i can change the file system of disk drive. and can i develop my own file system?

Comment: You could, but that would entail creating a custom device driver, force this to get loaded instead of the default one and at the same time make sure that other drives not related to your project still loads the normal device driver. I doubt that going to such extremes are necessary. If you explain in your original post why you need to prevent access in the first place, maybe people might be able to give advice on ways to design around your problem.

Comment: @ahmedragab Also, why would the files be in risk of being deleted?